# Kohana Formo subform will not render as part of main form

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I can never get the subform of the Kohana Formo module to work right. I wonder if I'm doing something fundementaly wrong or if this is an issue I should try reporting.

I can't even seem to be able to get the example out of the guide to work.
/index.php/guide/formo/formo.subforms

```
$address = Formo::form()
    ->add('street')
    ->add('city')
    ->add('zip');

$user_form = Formo::form()
    ->add('first name')
    ->add('last name')
    ->add('address', 'group', $address);
```

The subform fields will not render and I don't seem to be able to access them either.

Trying the next step in the guide

```
$user_form->address->street->val();
```

Yields "Call to a member function val() on a non-object."

Am I missing something here, is it a bug, or is this functionality just isn't fully developed?

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote it, the $address subform is being added as the value for `$user_form->address`.

The solution is just to add the address subform:

```
$address = Formo::form()
    ->add('street')
    ->add('city')
    ->add('zip');

$user_form = Formo::form()
    ->add('first name')
    ->add('last name')
    ->add('address', 'group', $address);
```